# How to add selected branches to My Branches in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

How can I add some branches to 'My Branches' in TeamCity?

So that I can see selected branches only while viewing some configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it manually: those are just the branches with your recent commits.

According to the [What's New in TeamCity 2018.2](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/What's+New+in+TeamCity+2018.2) `Other Improvements` section:

> The branch chooser now has the “My Branches” option displaying the
>   branches with the recent commits of the current user only.